# Is it possible to connect Debezium into Postgres slave in version above 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I found this limitation in Debezium documentation:

> PostgreSQL 9.6 only supports logical replication slots on master servers. This means that a replica in a PostgreSQL cluster cannot be configured for logical replication, and consequently that the Debezium PostgreSQL Connector can only connect and communicate with the master server.

Is this limitation is also apply for PostgreSQL in versions above `9.6`?
It is possible use Debezium with PostgreSQL slave in versions: `10.x` and `11.x`?

Answer (score 2):

This limitation also exists in PostgreSQL 10 and 11. There are plans to remove it, but none have been committed so far.